# Isomorphism between $T$ and $O$ - Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $D$ an integer such that it is not a perfect square in
>   $\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> If $D \equiv 1$ mod $4$, the set $$T:= \{\left( \begin{matrix} a & b
>  \\ \frac{(D-1)b}{4} & a+b \\ \end{matrix} \right) : a, b \in
>  \mathbb{Z} \}$$ is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which is isomorphic
>   with the ring $$O := \{a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}: a, b \in \mathbb{Z}
> \}$$

My problem is to find a such isomorphism. However, I find this relation : $$\det \left( \begin{matrix} a & b
 \\ \frac{(D-1)b}{4} & a+b \\ \end{matrix} \right)$$ $$= a(a+b)-\frac{b^2(D-1)}{4}$$ $$= (a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2})(a+b\frac{1-\sqrt{D}}{2})$$

and $D \equiv 1$ mod $4$ $\iff$ $(\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2})(\frac{1-\sqrt{D}}{2}) = -k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Does someone could give me a little hint to help me complete this problem?